# PHP refresh countdown stop at zero

Tags: php, subtraction

I have a website that shows a random number to new visitors and stores that number in a cookie.

If the user refreshes the page then it pulls the cookies value and subtracts a random number between 1 & 3 before displaying it.

This is what I have hacked together so far:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['places'])) {
$places=$_COOKIE['places'];
$decrease=mt_rand(1, 3);
$places=$places-$decrease;
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie('places', $places, $expire);
}
else {
$randomString = mt_rand ( 11 , 23 );
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie('places', $randomString, $expire);
$places=$randomString;
}
?>
```

The issue I have is that if you carried on refreshing (which I doubt anyone would do), it carries on through 0 into negative numbers. I have looked through php.net but I can't find the solution I need to stop this happening.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm misreading this, but have you tried replacing:

```
$places = $places - $decrease;
```

With this:

```
if ( $decrease > $places ) {
    $places = 0
} else {
    $places = $places - $decrease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['places'])) {
    $places=$_COOKIE['places'];
    $decrease=mt_rand(1, 3);
    $places=$places-$decrease;
    if($places < 0) 
      $places = 0;
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie('places', $places, $expire);
}
else {
    $randomString = mt_rand ( 11 , 23 );
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie('places', $randomString, $expire);
    $places=$randomString;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? If $places - $decrease will result in a negative number, add the number instead. I think it should achieve the effect you want...

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['places'])) {
    $places=$_COOKIE['places'];
    $decrease=mt_rand(1, 3);
        if(($places - $decrease) <= 0) {
            $places = $places + $decrease;
        } else {
            $places=$places-$decrease;
        }
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie('places', $places, $expire);
}
```

If your goal is to limit the floor to zero, then the other answers are simpler than mine. If maintaining a random number is essential, I think adding would be better.